# SequelizeJS - Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble with my data models in Sequelize. From what I can gather, it has something to do with my associations. I'm a bit lost on what is throwing this error. I have a 1:m association between Admin and Filter, and another model, User.

**Admin**

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Admin = sequelize.define("Admin", {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Admin.hasMany(models.Filter,{
          foreignKey: 'id',
        })
      }
    },
    freezeTableName:true
  });

  Admin.sync()

  return Admin;
};
```

**Filter**

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Filter = sequelize.define("Filter", {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    image_uri: DataTypes.STRING,
    tags: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
    ownerId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    isFeatured: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    AdminId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Filter.belongsTo(models.Admin, {
          foreignKey: 'id',
          as: 'admin'
        });
      }
    },
    freezeTableName:true
  });

  Filter.sync();

  return Filter;
};
```

**User**

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    age_range: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName:true
  });

  User.sync()

  return User;
};
```

When I create a new filter, I'm able to create and save the first, but any created after that, I get this error: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError`

Also, when I start up the app and the tables are created, I get these two errors: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "Admin" does not exist` and `Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error`

Comment: What about in your Filter belongsTo Admin set the foreignKey Attribute as "AdminId" instead of "id"  and in the  Admin hasMany Filters remove the object passed as second argument (which have foreignKey attribute)

Comment: @GonzaloBahamondez Those errors still seem to persist when the app starts up and is created. Could it be something with the order in which tables are created and synced? Also, the unique constraint error probably only has something to do with `User`, since it is the only model with a unique attribute?

Comment: @Jordan found a solution?

Comment: @avck Unfortunately, I can't recall.

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue, but everything seems to work fine so I'm ignoring it, but would love to know where it is coming from. I see no issues with my associations.